# the buffer in server doesn't read the value that client sent

Tags: java, sockets

The client sends data (string) to the server, and the server must read it, but in my case the server didn't read the data (value) that the client sent, and I didn't know where is the problem exactly, because normally the steps to read data are all correct in the server side

Client side:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(address, authenticationServerPort);
username = username + "\n"; // to send username through socket without
String h=getUserInput();
        
// waiting
// Send the message to the server
// send public key
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
System.out.println(h);
bw.write(h);
bw.flush();
System.out.println("Message sent to the Authentication server : "+ h);
```

Server side:

```
Socket clientSocket = null;
try {

    System.out.println("Server Running");

    int serverPort = 8029; // the server port we are using

    ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

    List<BlockChain> resultList = new ArrayList<BlockChain>();
             
    while (true) {
        clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(is);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        System.out.println(isr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String request = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("the msg receving from client is : "+request);
                  
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())));
               
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
        }

    }
            
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();// TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Someone tell me where is the problem exactly.

Comment: [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) is looking to read in a *line*, which is a sequence of characters that terminates in a line-ending sequence, either a `\n`, or a `\r`, or a `\r\n`. But how can you be sure that `h` ends with a line-ending sequence in the client at `bw.write(h);`.

Comment: Thank you sir  .I have add this line in the client h+="\n";
and it works